# WatchKit 2.0 Detect When APNS Is Received

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, watchkit

I am creating an Apple Watch application which has a chat feature. I would like to update the chat conversation whenever the watch app is running and an APNS message is received. I know in the `AppDelegate`, the function

```
application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

can be used, but that's only when the device application is running in the foreground, not background. In the `WKUserNotificationInterfaceController`, there is the function `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, but that is only used when using a Dynamic Notification. Is it possible to have the watch application process a remote notification that is received when not using Dynamic Notifications and is running in the foreground?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating a WatchKit app, and using APNS, there's few things you need to know about how a push notification actually work on the Watch side.

1) It's the iOS system which choose wether or not the notification is handled by Watch, based on user activity (iPhone locked/unlocked; Watch is used/not used...).

> When one of your app’s local or remote notifications arrives on the user’s iPhone, iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone or on the Apple Watch. See [Doc Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html)

2) For the iOS side you can handle all your notifications in `didReceiveRemoteNotificationapplication(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` ==> you can check wether or not your app is in foreground + handle silent notifications.

3) There is two distinct entry points for notifications on the Watch side:

- As you said, there's the`WKUserNotificationInterfaceController` which is called when your WatchKit app is not used.
- And there's `didReceiveRemoteNotification(_:)` in your `ExtensionDelegate` class, which is called when your WatchKit app is running. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtensionDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKExtensionDelegate/didReceiveRemoteNotification:) for complete documentation.

If you need to update your app while it's running, through APNS, you should handle it in this last method ;)

Hope it'll help you!

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I needed.